# Adding a new column to a dataframe based on the values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I do have two `csv` files, I am using pandas to read the data.

The `train.csv` contains values, with headers `id, sentiment`

```
87,Positive
10,Positive
7,Neutral
```

The `text.csv` contains values, with headers `id, text`

```
7,hello, I think the price if high...
87, you can call me tomorow...
....
```

I would like to insert the text from `text.csv` into `train.csv` so the result would be:

```
87,Positive, you can call me tomorow...
```

Can any one help with pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

train= pd.read_csv("train.csv")
text= pd.read_csv("text.csv")

# this does not work
combined= pd.merge(train, text, on=['id'])
```

`Note` Some Ids may not be in the files, so I need to set null if the id does not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easy way can be

```py
pd.merge(train, test, on='id', how='outer')
```

As per pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), if you use `how` as `outer`, it will take all keys

Answer (score 1):

set the indices on the two dataframes, then add the columns:

```py
train.set_index('id').sentiment + text.set_index('id').text
```

Comment: the files already have headers, I tried but does not work, also, it may happen that some IDs not exists

Comment: always shows empty, the 3 headers show up, but not data ?!